# NP - hardness of school scheduling problem with a restriction

Tags: computational-complexity, np

I do have a real-life scheduling problem for a special education school.
Basically, i have a binary variable containing teachers, subject, time slot and rooms as indices.

The goal is to assign each teacher, needed subject and room such that the constraints all are fullfilled. The constraints are really heavy, so we thought that it might be NP-hard.

We were able to reduce it to a simple machine scheduling problem, but we ran accross an issue:
Our time slots available are constant at 40 (5 days, 8 slots each day). I checked in the book "Computers and Intractability" for problems to reduce to for a proof, but all of them require to have a variable amount of time slots to be NP-hard.

Is there anyone that can give a hint on a problem i could maybe reduce it to?

Comment: Well, in real-life problems, *everything* is ultimately bounded by a constant. Modelling it by a (necessarily unbounded) problem from theoretical computer science only gives an approximation of its real complexity, and you have some discretion in choosing which parameters behave as if they were unbounded variables. Depending on the setup, 40 may actually be quite a lot for an exponential-time algorithm, so it might be modelled better by treating this parameter as unbounded.

Comment: Modern SAT solvers and CSP solvers, like [glucose](http://www.labri.fr/perso/lsimon/glucose/) and [Picat](http://picat-lang.org/), may help.

Comment: @momo I second the suggestion of using a SAT solver, especially given the size and nature of your problem.

Comment: We can already solve the problem using Fico Xpress. This is more of the theoretical point of view where i really liked to actually prove that it is NP hard for my paper.
Thats why i had trouble with arguing why i could actually treat the 40 as unbounded..